# How to save a UIBezierPath to an existing UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibezierpath

I can't figure out how i can save my drawn path to an UIImage?
I know that I have to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and something like [drawImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.size.width, drawImage.size.height)];
But I don't know where to put it in my touch functions.

I need to save every path to the image, because I want to be able to change the color and alpha values after each drawn line.
With this code, all the lines will be adjusted in color and width at the same time when I change the values.

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImage: (UIImageView*) image
{
    ...
    paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    drawImage = image;
    self.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:drawImage];
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [brushPattern setStroke];
    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    // Drawing code
    //[myPath stroke];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [paths addObject:myPath];
    [myPath release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your earlier question, I am assuming that the image view is a subview of this custom view object. You will need to maintain a mutable array of paths in this class. Initialize it at `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and close the path at `touchesEnded:withEvent:`. Push the path into the array. At every touch event (began, moved, ended), call a method that updates the image view's image after adding the touch point to the path.

Updating the image will involve creating an empty image context and then iterating over all paths in your array and the current path while stroking them. Once you're done drawing, generate the image object from the context and set it to the image. Pretty straightforward until we notice that each path might differ in attributes. To deal with this you should create a container class for the path which will hold the attributes about the path. Push an object of this class for every path into the array rather than the path itself. This way you can maintain state for your view.

Comment: How can I update the image views image? I don't understand how I can put the path in my image view. Because I only set a point to the path but never link the path to this image view.

Comment: Have created a [`sample project`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/Beziers.zip) that will give you a basic idea. I am pushing the paths into the array and using the same stroke color in the end to draw them. Like mentioned, you will have to create a composite object that stores color information about the path and the path itself and push that object into the array.

Comment: Thank you! Now i got it. ;-) But my image view contains some drawings when i pass it to this paint controller. So right now it will be overwritten. How can i add this content to the image context, so the paths are above this image ?

Comment: got it, sorry. I use this [drawImage.image drawInRect:self.drawImage.bounds]; to draw my image before the paths will be drawn in updateDrawingBoard. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Was no good idea. Now I made a function in which I combine the loaded image with the just drawn paths and save it to filesystem. So it's working!

Comment: @Deepak Would you mind looking at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284257/uibezierpath-in-nsdictionary-is-it-possible  I think there is a problem with touch events and NSDictionary.

Comment: @madmax Can you tell, how you combined loaded image with drawn paths?

Answer (score 1):

There is one way out and very simple infact , each time you draw a path object you can save it in an increamental image , just create it at a place where needed and then show this image in draw rect before drawing something else.

here is the sample code:

```
  - (void)drawBitmap 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [strokeColor setStroke];
    if (!incrementalImage) // first time draw; paint background white by ...
    {
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds]; // enclosing bitmap by a rectangle defined by another UIBezierPath object
        [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"two.jpg"]] setFill];
        //[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        [rectpath fill]; // filling it with white
        NSLog(@"========== ... drawBitmap .. CALLED=======");
    }
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    for(NSDictionary *_pathDict in pathArray)
    {
        [((UIColor *)[_pathDict valueForKey:@"color"]) setStroke]; // this method will choose the color from the receiver color object (in this case this object is :strokeColor)
        [[_pathDict valueForKey:@"path"] strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    }
    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
```

After that just call this increamental image in drawRect: , so that user has a illusion of continuous drawing and you can then save this image point of time:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

     [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect];
     [[dict_path objectForKey:@"color"] setStroke]; // this method will choose the color from the receiver color object (in this case this object is :strokeColor)

     [[dict_path objectForKey:@"path"] strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

}
```

May be you need to modify some code according to your own need.Hope this help someone