# UIBezierPath in NSDictionary - is it possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary, uibezierpath

I am trying to save a UIBezierPath and some other values in an NSDictionary.

I write in the dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableArray *paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

touchesBegan:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.drawImage];

path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPath] retain];
path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
path.lineWidth = brushSize;
[path moveToPoint:touchPoint];

[self updateDrawingBoard];
}
```

touchesEnded:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.drawImage];

[path addLineToPoint:touchPoint];

NSDictionary   *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: path, @"path", r, @"red", g, @"green", b, @"blue", alpha, @"alpha", brushSize, @"size", nil];
[paths addObject:dict];
[dict release];
[path release];
path = nil;

[self updateDrawingBoard];
}
```

And read it like this one :

```
- (void) updateDrawingBoard {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.bounds.size);

[[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:alpha] setStroke];
NSLog(@"count: %d", [paths count]);
for ( NSDictionary *dict in paths ) {
    NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);

    //Here I get the error
    UIBezierPath *p = [dict objectForKey:@"path"];
    p.lineWidth = [[dict objectForKey:@"size"]floatValue];
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:[[dict objectForKey:@"red"]floatValue] 
                     green:[[dict objectForKey:@"green"]floatValue] 
                      blue:[[dict objectForKey:@"blue"]floatValue] 
                     alpha:[[dict objectForKey:@"alpha"]floatValue]] setStroke];
    [p stroke];
}

[path stroke];

self.drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

But I get this error:

```
[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b0210
```

Don't think that I am doing something wrong.

Dictionary log:

```
dict: (
"<UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer: 0x1b30a0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=delayed:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>>",
"<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x1b0b60; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>; must-fail = {\n        <UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x1ec7c0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>>\n    }>",
"<UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x1ec7c0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>; must-fail-for = {\n        <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x1b0b60; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>>\n    }>"
  )
```

Dictionary without paths:

```
NSDictionary   *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:r], @"red", 
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:g], @"green", 
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:b], @"blue", 
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:alpha], @"alpha", 
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:brushSize], @"size", nil];
[paths addObject:dict];
[dict release];
```

Log output:

```
count: 0
2011-06-09 10:46:28.813 L3T[913:207] count: 1
2011-06-09 10:46:28.815 L3T[913:207] dict: {
alpha = 1;
blue = 0;
green = 1;
red = 0;
size = 5;
}
2011-06-09 10:46:32.552 L3T[913:207] count: 1
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Ends also with a crash.

Comment: @madmax What does a `NSLog(@"dict: %@", [dict class]);` yield?

Comment: You should add more code as the bug is most certainly within other parts of your sources. Right now you are handling something that actually is an NSArray as if it were a NSDictionary.

Comment: When you create your dictionary with objects and keys you put RGBA values as pure numbers, not objects. You have to wrap them into NSNumber. May be you do it, but you didn't show it anywhere i your code sample.

Comment: @Nava Oh, ok. Then that's another error. But my error occurs with UIBezierPath. Don't know what else I could post, that's all the code necessary I think.

Comment: I think the problem is linked with touch events. I call updateDrawingBoard when a touch begins, moves and ends. So maybe the values in the dictionary are changing too fast or something similar ?

Comment: You didn't show the code where you're creating your bezier path. May be it's being created with one of convenience functions, that don't require release... In the dictionary log BTW there is no mention about the key 'path', although you're trying to get its value. So it's pretty hard to understand what's wrong there

Comment: You don't need to release the dict in your code sample, since you create it with convenience function, which does the autorelease for allocated instance. This can explain your crash there. In the code sample where you create your dictionary with 'path' key you have the same problem. dict is autoreleased for you, you don't need to call a release function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted reads fine. It should work fine too but I think the error lies elsewhere. The log,

```
dict: (
"<UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer: 0x1b30a0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=delayed:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>>",
"<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x1b0b60; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>; must-fail = {\n        <UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x1ec7c0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>>\n    }>",
"<UIScrollViewPagingSwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x1ec7c0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=_handleSwipe:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>; must-fail-for = {\n        <UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x1b0b60; state = Possible; enabled = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x1e0380>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UIScrollView 0x1e0380>)>>\n    }>"
  )
```

indicates that at least one of the objects pushed into the `path` array is an array and not an `NSDictionary` object. You're not doing it in the code above so it must be elsewhere. I am somehow guessing that you should search for `view.gestureRecognizers` within the code in a form similar to,

```
[paths addObject:view.gestureRecognizers];
```

where `view` is a scrollview object. You will have to take it off unless there was a reason you did it.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the code. I don't know where the ScrollView is coming from. This view here is a subview of another ViewController which is a subview of a ScrollView. Added some code, also a dictionary without the paths, only with NSNumber Objects. But I still get a segmentation fault.